# DRUPAL_ROOT undefined on module installation

Tags: debugging

I try to install the live_agent module. When I go to enable the module, I get the following errors:

> Notice: Use of undefined constant DRUPAL_ROOT - assumed 'DRUPAL_ROOT' in /sites/all/modules/live_agent/live_agent.module on line 319
>
> Warning: require_once(DRUPAL_ROOT/includes/errors.inc) [function.require-once]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /sites/all/modules/live_agent/live_agent.module on line 319
>
> Fatal error: require_once() [function.require]: Failed opening required 'DRUPAL_ROOT/includes/errors.inc' (include_path='.:/usr/share/pear:/usr/share/php') in /sites/all/modules/live_agent/live_agent.module on line 319

The code causing the error is the following one.

```
 /* 318 */ function live_agent_buttons_form(&$form_state) {
 /* 319 */   global $base_url;
 /* 320 */ 
 /* 321 */   $settings = new liveagent_Settings();
 /* 322 */   $la_buttons_grid = $settings->getButtonsGridRecordset();
 /* 323 */   $recordset = $la_buttons_grid->toArray();
 /* 324 */ 
             // ...
 /* 373 */ }
```

Any help on debugging this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to DA! If you read the code and the error message, you'll see that line 319 is _not_ a `require_once` as the error message states, so you appear to have pasted the wrong code. Bugs in modules a considered off-topic for this site.

Comment: @Letharion I pasted [the code that is at line 319 of the module file](http://drupalcode.org/project/live_agent.git/blob/refs/heads/7.x-1.x:/live_agent.module).

Comment: Do you have APC enabled?  If so, try disabling it temporarily.

Comment: @kiamlaluno I see. Well, that combination of code and error message still doesn't seem to make sense to me. :)

Comment: @Letharion The errors seem caused from the autoload function, but I don't know why the error is for that line.

Answer (score 1):

The error about the undefined constant `DRUPAL_ROOT` could be caused from the index.php file that is corrupted, or that is returned corrupted from APC, or similar extension. `DRUPAL_ROOT` is always defined when Drupal bootstraps.

```
/**
 * Root directory of Drupal installation.
 */
define('DRUPAL_ROOT', getcwd());

require_once DRUPAL_ROOT . '/includes/bootstrap.inc';
drupal_bootstrap(DRUPAL_BOOTSTRAP_FULL);
menu_execute_active_handler();
```

As for why the error message is reported for that module when a function that doesn't contain any reference to the constant is executed, I think that is caused from the autoload function Drupal registers, [drupal_autoload_class()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!bootstrap.inc/function/drupal_autoload_class/7), which is trying to load the file containing the class.

Answer (score 0):

Check your settings.php file. You might have either.

You set the wrong base URL, or maybe you did not set one and this module requires it.